# "kubectl get nodes" does not show the right version number

Tags: kubernetes

Could anybody help how I can change the version number shown from "kubectl get nodes"? The binaries are compiled from source. "kubectl version" shows the correct version, but "kubectl get nodes" not.

Here is what I get from `kubectl version`:

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7+", GitVersion:"v1.7.0-alpha.3.18+20457ee68dac55", GitCommit:"20457ee68dac552                                                                        7f6d9307fddcd2bd92389e5d4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-05-09T22:27:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.1", Compiler:"gc", Platf                                                                        orm:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7+", GitVersion:"v1.7.0-alpha.3.18+20457ee68dac55", GitCommit:"20457ee68dac552                                                                        7f6d9307fddcd2bd92389e5d4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-05-09T22:24:55Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.1", Compiler:"gc", Platf                                                                        orm:"linux/amd64"}

And here is what I get from `kubectl get nodes`:

[kubectl get nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijlGO.png)

I deployed the cluster using this script:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/cluster/kube-up.sh

This script will finally use ...release-1.2/cluster/ubuntu/download-release.sh to download the binaries. I commented the call to download-release.sh and put my own binaries compiled from the up-to-date sources into ubuntu/binaries folder.

But if I didn't comment that call to download-release.sh, and let the whole kube-up.sh finish launch a cluster with an older version kubernetes (1.2.6 in this example), this version number will be remembered by "kubectl get nodes", even later on I commented the call to download-release.sh and replace with newest binaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you paste your actual output? `kubectl get nodes` does not return a version number. Perhaps you meant `kubectl describe nodes`?

In any case, `kubectl version` will return the version of the leader `apiserver`, not of individual nodes in the cluster. What has happened in your case is that you have installed the desired version on your `apiserver` but not your nodes. Or you have installed the new version on your nodes but you have not properly restarted them.

More detail is necessary to help you resolve this though. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Yes, `kubectl version` only shows the version of `apiserver`. The versions from `kubectl get nodes` are the versions of `kubelet`. And the wrong version was due to not using the right `kubelet` binaries.